# Excel VBA Vlookup single character

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have a string that I need to convert to it's hexadecimal equivalent.  The Hex values can change from situation to situation for the text characters so on a second worksheet I made a table that I can modify as needed with my A-Z...a-z..1-0 characters and their associated hex value.

I've confirmed that I've set the range for my VLookup correctly, and I've confirmed that I'm passing it a character one at a time, but it insists that it can't find any values on the Vlookup.  What am I missing here?

```
Sub LoopThroughString()
Dim wbBook As Workbook
Dim tblSheet As Worksheet
Dim wrkSheet As Worksheet
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim myString, myChar As String
Dim vRng, chrRng As Range
Dim sRes As Variant

Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
With wbBook
    Set wrkSheet = .Worksheets("wrkSheet")
    Set tblSheet = .Worksheets("tblSheet")
End With

With tblSheet
    Set vRng = .Range("A1", .Range("B1").End(xlDown))
End With

myString = Range("A1").Value 'define string


For Counter = 1 To Len(myString)
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Clear
    myChar = Mid(myString, Counter, 1)
    sRes = Application.VLookup(myChar, vRng, 1, False)
    If IsError(sRes) = False Then
        Cells(2, 1 + Counter).Value = chrRng
    Else
        Debug.Print "Count not find value: " & myChar
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Edit: Here is a screenshot of the table with characters to lookup
[image]

Comment: is your table set up as `char | hex value`? show us a picture of your lookup table

Comment: I have edited the question to include the table.  I've tried it both a char | hex value and as hex value | char, both failed to find any values

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I actually just noticed that when I have it arranged char | hex value I'm not getting any errors in my Debug.Print, it's just not putting anything in my cells.  A quick check and I found that while trying to fix the issue I had assigned the wrong variable to be written to my cell.

Comment: I believe the problem is in your variable declaration. You wrote `Dim vRng, chrRng As Range`. You need to write `Dim vRng as Range, chrRng As Range`. The way you wrote only declares `chrRng` as Range. `vRng` is a variant type.

Comment: Good catch. Also see my point above as well. That may trip you up in the future, if not now.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman oh, that's true.  I'll modify the code in the answer I did to make sure all variables are correctly defined!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that I had initially arranged my table as Hex Value | Char as @ScottHoltzman pointed out I needed it arranged Char | Hex Value.  The reason it appeared not to be working was because I had an unused variable being written to the cell instead of the sRes variable.  Working code below, however it is not case sensitive

```
Sub LoopThroughString()
Dim wbBook As Workbook
Dim tblSheet As Worksheet
Dim wrkSheet As Worksheet
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim myString as String, myChar As String
Dim vRng As Range
Dim sRes As Variant

Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
With wbBook
    Set wrkSheet = .Worksheets("wrkSheet")
    Set tblSheet = .Worksheets("tblSheet")
End With

With tblSheet
    Set vRng = .Range("A1", .Range("B1").End(xlDown))
End With

With wrkSheet
    myString = .Range("A1").Value 'define string
End With


For Counter = 1 To Len(myString)
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Clear
    myChar = Mid(myString, Counter, 1)
    sRes = Application.VLookup(myChar, vRng, 2, False)
    If IsError(sRes) = False Then
        Debug.Print ""
        Cells(2, 1 + Counter).Value = sRes
    Else
        Debug.Print "Couldn't find value: " & myChar
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Since my initial question was only about using VLookup I provided the answer that was most in line with that question as "THE" answer.  However, after doing the Vlookup I also needed it to be case sensitive, something VLookup doesn't do without extra steps.  As a result I changed my code to the following and used the "Find" function instead of VLookup to accomplish the same results, but with case-sensitivity.

```
Sub LoopThroughString()
Dim wbBook As Workbook
Dim tblSheet As Worksheet
Dim wrkSheet As Worksheet
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim myString As String, myChar As String
Dim vRng As Range, rRng As Range

Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
With wbBook
    Set wrkSheet = .Worksheets("wrkSheet")
    Set tblSheet = .Worksheets("tblSheet")
End With

With tblSheet
    Set vRng = .Range("A1", .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
End With

With wrkSheet
    myString = .Range("A1").Value 'define string
End With

'Debug.Print myString

For Counter = 1 To Len(myString)
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Clear
    myChar = Mid(myString, Counter, 1)
    'Debug.Print myChar
    Set rRng = vRng.Find(myChar, MatchCase:=True)
    If rRng Is Nothing Then

    Else
        With tblSheet
            myChar = .Cells(rRng.Row, 2).Value
        End With

        With wrkSheet
            .Cells(2, 1 + Counter).Value = myChar
        End With

    End If

Next

End Sub
```